# Sliding Panel from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a sliding panel and somebody gave me this code http://jsfiddle.net/czBJU/3/    and this  http://jsfiddle.net/Lstmn/1/  but neither of them works.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/m4jVz/

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).load()` accepts a function, not an object:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Unless you're explicitly waiting for *all* resources to load before binding your event handler, I suggest you stick to `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`.

You also misspelled the `id` attribute of your HTML element:

```
<a id="porfolio_button">Slide Open Portfolio</a>
         ^^
```

Here's a fixed version of your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/czBJU/7/